# Cromwell - controlling core/mem usage, and CallCaching, while running locally?

Tags: microarray, illumina, wdl

I'm sitting on a mountain of microarray (.idat files) data, and have been tasked to analyze it. I chose the MoChA pipeline, developed by the Broad Institute. It runs through Cromwell, of which I know quite little as it is written in Java and I think it's mostly meant to be applied in HPC environments.

Anyway, my research group does not currently have access to any fancy clusters so I'm running it locally. I could get most of the data through after creating a swap file of size 256GB, but for the remaining sets I would need terabytes of RAM... all because the Cromwell engine doesn't limit its resource usage.

Now, there's an option in the Cromwell config file "concurrent-jobs-limit", that would solve this resource problem, but when I attempt to use it, I get errors.

- Cromwell version used: 78
- Exact command used: https://pastebin.com/70ebMVE5
- Entire program log: https://pastebin.com/hQ8U3f86
- Configuration file contents (ctrl+F "concurrent-job"): https://pastebin.com/veDikew7

I tried adding the missing key (line 379) but it merely changes the error to https://pastebin.com/dxDHrKdk

I suspect the override of "LocalExample" (line 341) somehow removes invisible default settings... and right about there I'm out of my depth.

I have asked in the Cromwell slack channel already, no responses in two days. I asked in the Broad Institute forums and they said they don't support Cromwell. Sincerely hoping someone here knows enough about Cromwell to help. I'd really really appreciate it. :]

Joel